# Is weak connectivity sufficient for $0$ to be a simple eigenvalue of the weighted Laplacian?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-laplacian

$L$ is the weighted Laplacian of a weakly connected directed graph $G$,$$L=D-A$$ with the $L_{ij} \leq 0$ when $i \neq j$, $L_{ii} \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{ij}=0$.

**My question is:** Is $0$ a simple eigenvalue of $L$ ?

Comment: My example was wrong because I mixed up weakly connected and semiconnected.

Comment: @Ian: no problem

Comment: Also, your condition about the rank of $D$ is redundant: a weakly connected directed graph can only have one vertex with out-degree zero, because if there are two say $A,B$ then there is no path from $A$ to $B$ and also no path from $B$ to $A$ (since there are no paths from either of them to *anywhere*) so the graph is not weakly connected. (This case of two vertices with out-degree zero was the trick I was trying to pull in my answer attempt.)

Comment: I edited it, thanks.

Comment: Actually sorry, can you spell out your definition of weakly connected? It seems that the usual definition actually does allow my example, and if you merely explicitly prohibit having more than one vertex with out-degree zero then you can still do a trivial adjustment of my example (basically expand a vertex with out-degree zero into a cycle that you can't escape) to get a counterexample.

Comment: @Ian The definition of weakly connected is that if you replace the directed edges with undirected edges , then the resulting undirected graph is connected.

Comment: Then indeed you can do my example of $A \to B,C \to D,A \to C$, assuming that multiple vertices with out-degree zero are permitted. In this case the Laplacian has two rows of zeros. If they are not, then add in $B \to E,E \to B,D \to F,F \to D$. In this case the Laplacian doesn't have two rows of zeros but I think you still get a multiple eigenvector of zero anyway, at least with uniform edge weights (use eigenvectors concentrated on the cycles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample 1:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

which is to say $A \leftarrow B \rightarrow C$.

Counterexample 2:

In a previous version, you imposed a requirement that $D$ has a kernel with dimension at most $1$. You can make it zero, in fact, by doing this:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

This is two cycles plus a single vertex that enters both cycles. Now there are two eigenvectors with eigenvalue zero (as can be seen by the fact that rows 2 and 4 are multiples of each other and rows 3 and 5 are as well).